# How to display a date read from Firebase as ion-datetime element

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, timestamp, ionic4

In my ionic 4 application I am reading a timestamp from my firebase database and attempting to display it in the format of a ion-datetime element.

The page loads and displays ok but my ion-datetime field is blank and I'm getting the following error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous 
value: 'model: undefined'. Current value: 'model: Invalid Date'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:19006)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:18994)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:19096)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:21967)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:21956)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:22560)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22488)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (EditMatchPage.html:42)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:21855)
```

Here is my html code

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label  position="stacked">Match Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime
      [(ngModel)]="matchDate"
      displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY HH:mm"
      pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"
      min="2019"
      max="2020-12-31"
      value="{{currentMatchDetails?.date}}">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

and my .ts function which I don't think is relevant but I'll include it anyway

```
private async returnMatchDetails(matchId: string){     
    const matchDetailsSnapshot = await this.matchService.getMatch(matchId).get();
    this.currentMatchDetails = matchDetailsSnapshot.data();
    this.currentMatchDetails.id = matchDetailsSnapshot.id;      
}
```

Comment: You need to choose to use [(ngModel)] or value. In my project i use [(ngModel)] and it works fine

Comment: @jcmendes98 Could you give a bit more detail? In my html I am using [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 0):

You are using both `ngModel` and `value` attributes which is causing the issue as both are trying to update the field.

```html
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label  position="stacked">Match Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime
      [(ngModel)]="matchDate"
      displayFormat="D MMM, YYYY HH:mm"
      pickerFormat="DD MMM YYYY HH:mm"
      min="2019"
      max="2020-12-31">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

Where `matchDate` should be on your component:

```js
matchDate = currentMatchDetails ? currentMatchDetails.Date : new Date().toISOString();
```

Be careful with `currentMatchDetails.Date` as ionic docs states that it should be [ISO 8601 Datetime format](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthh-mmz).

Comment: So what your saying is I should remove the 'value' line of the html and where do I insert "matchDate = currentMatchDetails ? currentMatchDetails.Date : new Date().toISOString();" ?

Comment: I'm not actually trying to update the field in this instance - initially I'm just trying to display it. Currently its blank.